# Page numbers in beamer are sometimes covered up -- how to always display?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I'm displaying page numbers in a beamer document using this:

```
% my ``own'' boadilla, i.e. without the infolines
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

and page numbers generally show up, as I want. But on some slides,
when the text is written all the way to the bottom, page numbers are hidden,
since they are probably "beneath" the level of the text.  But since the text is usually on the left and the page numbers are on the right, I want the page numbers to show through.  I don't know what to search for since I think of this as "overlay" or "beneath" or "under", but those words all have several meanings and I can't get the one I want.  In web design terminology, what I want to do is change the "zIndex" of the footer.  Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal working example (See http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) showing the undesired behaviour?

Comment: Ahh, such wisdom.  I tried this and found the problem: on the bad frames that were hiding the page number, the issue was that I had copied them from an old presentation which occasionally started frames with

`\begin{frame}[plain]`

and this, obviously, prevents the page number from showing.  So answer solved!  thanks

Comment: you should consider either deleting this question or posting an answer yourself and accepting it. (This is for the sake of the software design of this website: if you leave this question unanswered, it will be automatically 'bumped' to front page every now and then.)